# Coffeescript loop issues

Tags: loops, while-loop, coffeescript

*This has been solved. I typed `if` insted of `while`. :(*

I am writing a program in Coffeescript (*Pencilcode.net*) to solve a problem i have been given is school. I have decided to use trial-and-error, but my loops are giving me problems. This is the code with sed loops:

```
speed -1
scale 0.5
jumpto -500,50
pen black, 1
bk 300
rt 90
fd 1000
lt 90
fd 500
jumpto -500, 50
[co_x,co_y]=getxy()
turnto 250,-124
if co_x < 250          #The problems start here, line 13
  fd 1
  [co_x,co_y]=getxy()
if co_y < 125          #Line 16
  turnto 250,125
  fd 1
  [co_x,co_y]=getxy()
```

The problems start at line 13. This loop just doesn't do **anything**, and the next loop, starting at line 16 trys to run at the same time, but also does **nothing**. So, my two questions are: What is wrong with the loops, and how can I make the second loop wait to start until the first one has finished.

***If you would like to look at what this code does, copy and paste it into [this](http://pencilcode.net/edit/myprogram) online compiler. (Pencilcode.net)***

**EDIT:** I have been able to fix the issue of both loops running at once by putting the second loop inside an `else` of the first:

```
if co_x < 250
  fd 1
  [co_x,co_y]=getxy()
else
  if co_y < 125
    turnto 250,125
    fd 1
    [co_x,co_y]=getxy()
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but that's an `if` statement, not a loop. It should say `while col_x < 250`, no?

Comment: Also to answer the second question *how can I make the second loop wait to start until the first one has finished*: the code doesn't execute asynchronously; in other words, it will, and does, wait until the previous statement is finished executing before proceeding to the next statement, and onwards from there. Hypothetically, if your first loop took a very long time to complete, you would be able to see that the activity of the second loop does not happen until the first one is complete. You can also verify this with a debugger.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be `while`. I'm an idiot. Sorry :P

Comment: In regards to your update a minute ago, what you've done there is make it so that the second `if` statement will only execute if the first `if` statement is false. I got the impression that you needed both statements to execute one after another, so this might not be the correct solution (which is a moot point now since we've discovered it was a wrong control statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...
Solved as said in question. (If you do try the code yourself, yes I know it looks stupid. That version is old and broken!)